# Getting invalid mail error during phpmailer bulk mail sending

Tags: php, phpmailer

php mailer is mass mail, but if a mail address in a record is incorrect, it stops sending mail. How can I skip that address and continue.

I RETURN ALL MY CODES FROM MY DATABASE TO LIST WITH FOREACH HERE
I didn't have a problem when I tried my codes on a array of two different emails of mine

```
<?php

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        //Server Ayarları
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
        $mail->Host="x";
        $mail->SMTPAuth= true;
        $mail->Username="x@x";
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Password="x;
        $mail->CharSet="utf8";
        $mail->Port=587;
        //Alıcı Ayarları
        $mail->setFrom('x', 'x');
        $gonulluler=$database->select($_SESSION["type"],"eposta");
        foreach ($gonulluler as $gonullu){
            $mail->addBCC($gonullu);
        }

        //Gönderi ayarları
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject=$baslik;
        $mail->Body=$icerik;
        if($mail->send()){
            $alert=array(
                "message"=>"Mail Başarılı Bir Şekilde Gönderildi",
                "type" => "success"
            );
        }else{
            $alert=array(
                "message"=>"Mail Gönderilirken Bir Hata İle Karşılaşıldı",
                "type" => "danger"
            );
        }

    }catch (Exception $e){
        $alert=array(
                "message"=>$e->getMessage(),
                "type" => "danger"
            );
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use for your mass mailing?

Comment: People will only be able to help you if you provide some code. Without the code one can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: I'm sorry I added my codes

Comment: You do realise that Blind copies `addBCC()` creates one email that every recipient can then view all the other recipients email addresses, if they have the faintest idea what the are doing. Not too secure

Comment: My guess is it is raising an exception, and you have not coded a way back from the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the email address is valid, and if the mailserver will respond, before using `$mail->addBCC()`. This function can do both:

```
function isValidEmailAddress($email, $performDomainCheck = FALSE)
// validate an email address, TRUE if the email address has the email address format and the domain exists
{
   $atSignIndex = strrpos($email,'@');
   // no @ sign
   if (is_bool($atSignIndex) && !$atSignIndex) return FALSE;
   // take parts
   $domain    = substr($email,$atSignIndex+1);
   $name      = substr($email,0,$atSignIndex);
   $domainLen = strlen($domain);
   $nameLen   = strlen($name);
   // name part length exceeded
   if ($nameLen < 1 || $nameLen > 64) return FALSE;
   // domain part length exceeded
   if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255) return FALSE;
   // local part starts or ends with '.'
   if ($name[0] == '.' || $name[$nameLen-1] == '.') return FALSE;
   // local part has two consecutive dots
   if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $name)) return FALSE;
   // character not valid in domain part
   if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain)) return FALSE;
   // domain part has two consecutive dots
   if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain)) return FALSE;
   // character not valid in local part unless local part is quoted
   if (!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',str_replace("\\\\","",$name)))
   {
     if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',str_replace("\\\\","",$name))) return FALSE;
   }
   // domain not found in DNS?
   if ($performDomainCheck)
   {
//     $domain = idn_to_ascii($domain);   function not known yet (php 5.3 on 24-10-2015)
     if (!(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A"))) return FALSE;
   }
   // it's oke
   return TRUE;
}
```

I didn't update the style of this function. It is not perfect, but using something like this will make your mass mailer work a lot better. Your code would look something like this:

```
    foreach ($gonulluler as $gonullu){
        if (isValidEmailAddress($gonullu, TRUE) {
            $mail->addBCC($gonullu);
        }
    }
```

You could add an `else` part to notify yourself of the invalid email addresses.

Comment: The cause of my problem was simpler than that, but I will start using the code, thank you. The reason for my problem was that a Turkish character was used in the mail. I encoded it with utf-8.